# vs2017 asp.net core 2 + Angular. npm seems to take forever to dowload

Tags: angular, npm, visual-studio-2017

Actually: VS2017 Pro latest updates + npm lastest versión.

When creating a blank asp.net core 2.0 Project with Angular (using the provided template) it seems to never end updating packages ("Build delayed until Bower/npm packages finish restoring"). In my last try it goes to 2 hours.

The Bower/npm Windows says: "PATH=.\node_modules.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Web\External\npm.CMD" install"

Also tried by command line with same results.

Does this leaves any log? Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Found an specific working method for me. Hope this helps: https://medium.com/@levifuller/building-an-angular-application-with-asp-net-core-in-visual-studio-2017-visualized-f4b163830eaa